# Trying to get folder path of file in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-docs

I am trying to create a function in Google Apps Script that finds the file path of the folder.
Here is the error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendParagraph' of null (line 20, file "Code")

```
function getRoot() {

  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var header = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getHeader();
  var name = doc.getName();
  var id = doc.getId();
  var txt = "Master Folder";
  var parents = [];
  var folders = DriveApp.getFileById(id).getParents();
  while (folders.hasNext()){
    var parent = folders.next();
    var n = parent.getName();
    parents.push(n);
  }
  var pLen = parents.length;
  for (i = 0; i < pLen; i++){
    txt = txt + "//" + parents[i];
  }

  var headerPar = header.appendParagraph(txt);


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to know the reason of the error message of `TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendParagraph' of null`.
- You want to remove the error.
- You want to retrieve the folder path of the active Google Document.

For this, how about this answer?

#### Modification points:

- In your script, I think that the reason of your error message is the header is not existing in the Google Document. By this, `header` retrieved by `getHeader()` is `null`, and then, the error occurs. So in this case, please add the header using `addHeader()`.
- `doc` of `var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();` can be used for `getHeader()`.
- If you want to retrieve the folder path from the root folder, I think that your script is required to be modified. In your current script, when the Google Document is put in the nested folders, only parent of the Document is retrieved.

When your script is modified using above points, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function getRoot() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();

  var header = doc.getHeader() || doc.addHeader();  // Modified

  var name = doc.getName();
  var id = doc.getId();
  var txt = "Master Folder";
  var parents = [];
  var folders = DriveApp.getFileById(id).getParents();

  // --- I modified below script
  while (folders.hasNext()) {
    var folder = folders.next();
    parents.push(folder.getName());
    folders = folder.getParents();
  }
  parents = parents.reverse();
  // ---

  var pLen = parents.length;
  for (i = 0; i < pLen; i++){
    txt = txt + "//" + parents[i];
  }
  var headerPar = header.appendParagraph(txt);
}
```

- By this modification, when the header is existing, `doc.getHeader()` is used. When the header is not existing, `doc.addHeader()` is used. And, when the active Document is put to the folder path like `root -> folder1 -> folder2`, `Master Folder//MyDrive//folder1//folder2` is put to the header.

#### References:

- [getHeader()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#getheader)
- [addHeader()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#addheader)

Comment: Yes thank you! You answered it perfectly. I should have been more specific with my question. Thank you again!

Comment: If you use `unshift(folder.getName())` instead of `push`, you don't need to `reverse`.

Comment: Also, the `folders = folder.getParents();` is unnecessary. `var folder = folders.next()` already advances the iterator to the next folder up.

Comment: @Leif Messinger LOAF Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `Also, the folders = folder.getParents(); is unnecessary. folders.next() advances the iterator to the next folder up.`. Can I ask you about the details of it? In my answer, each parent folder is retrieved with `folders = folder.getParents()`. By this, file path of the OP's goal is obtained. If my understanding was not correct, please tell me. I would like to modify it. If you can cooperate, I'm glad.

Comment: Well, the original folders is `var folders = DriveApp.getFileById(id).getParents();` and `getParents()` gives an iterator to all of the parents. When you iterate through the list, `.next()` pops off the next folder as it returns it. So, `folders` already equals `folder.getParents();` because that would be the next one in `folders` after `.next()` is called.

Comment: @Leif Messinger LOAF Thank you for replying. In my proposed script, `folders` of `var folders = DriveApp.getFileById(id).getParents();` is overwritten by `folders = folder.getParents();`. By this, the parent folders of each parent folder are retrieved. From your reply, if `folders = folder.getParents();` is replaced with `folders = folder.next();`, I think that an error occurs. If my understanding of your reply was not correct, I apologize.

Comment: No problem. We're all learning